# Does a right angle triangle ABC, right angled at A has A-symmedian?

Tags: geometry, contest-math, euclidean-geometry

A symmedian is defined to be the isogonal of a median in a triangle .

In EGMO , **lemma 4.24 (Constructing the Symmedian)**,which states, "Let $X$ be the intersection of the tangents to $(ABC)$ at $B$ and $C$. Then line $AX$ is a symmedian."

My question is what happens to a right angle triangle , when we do this construction, the tangent lines don't meet . Is this construction of symmedian limited to only acute triangles and obtuse triangles.

The author of the book hasn't commented anything about this .

Though , by a simple angle chase, we can see that for a right angle triangle, the symmedian is the altitude. [image]

Can someone clarify ?

Note: By EGMO, I mean the book, Euclidean Geometry in Mathematical Olympiads by Evan Chen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the projective real plane, if $A$ is a right angle then
the tangents at $B$ and $C$ both are perpendicular to the side $BC$
and therefore are parallel to each other and meet at a point at infinity.
Let this point at infinity be $X$.
Then the line $AX$ is parallel to the tangents at $B$ and $C,$
and therefore it also is perpendicular to side $BC$.
The altitude from $A$ to $BC$ lies along line $AX,$ as required.

You can also do this without a point at infinity if you are willing to consider limiting cases for $A$ an acute angle approaching a right angle and $A$ an obtuse angle approaching a right angle.

Comment: How did you get that AX is parallel to the the tangents ?

Comment: All lines through a point at infinity are parallel.

Comment: Granted, projective geometry might be a bit outside the scope of a book titled "Euclidean Geometry in Mathematical Olympiads," although perhaps it would be better if it were included.

Comment: No, it is there in the book, but it is the 9th chapter, I am in the 4th chapter .

Comment: If you work strictly in the Euclidean plane, parallel lines do not intersect, so if $A$ is a right angle then $X$ does not exist. Since $X$ does not exist, the line $AX$ also does not exist, and it is vacuously true that $AX$ is a symmedian as well as anything else you want it to be. But based on the title, it sounds like this is a how-to-solve-it book; it may be that in the case where $X$ does not exist the author assumed you would know the symmedian is an altitude and you wouldn't need the lemma.

Comment: actually EGMO, defined that every line passes through point at infinity ..

Comment: In the projective plane, every line passes through _a_ point at infinity. But there is a whole line at infinity consisting of points at infinity, one point for each set of parallel lines.

Answer (score 1):

[image]
Another way to define the symmedian is to reflect the median in the angle bisector.

This definition will not encounter any problem for a right angle.

In your case ... note that the tangent lines at $B$ and $D$ and $CE$ are all parallel ... and as such will concur at infinity.